# return valid json content after curl call

Tags: json

I use curl to get a feed from the facebook graph :

```
            $ch = curl_init();
            $options = array(
                CURLOPT_URL         => $url,
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => true,
                CURLOPT_HEADER      => false,
                CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION  => true,
                CURLOPT_ENCODING        => "",
                // CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER  => true,
                // CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT   => 120,
                // CURLOPT_TIMEOUT      => 120,
                // CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS        => 10,
                CURLOPT_USERAGENT       => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0'
            );
            curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );

            $resultat = curl_exec($ch);
            $code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
            curl_close($ch);

            // return
            $answer = array(
                'response' => 'ok',
                'resultat' => $resultat
            );
```

with cakePHP (i added `$this->RequestHandler->respondAs('json');`).

but there is a problem in the return :
[image]

the lines are not correctly displayed, my json reader can't read this, so what is the good option to correct that ? I tried json_encode/decode but it's not better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to decode your json and encode it again.

`$answer = '{ "key": "Your json values" }';
 $answer  = json_encode(json_decode($answer));`